# How to call REST API using CURL & SAML TOKEN Auth

Tags: json, rest, curl, saml, poster

My Url is Like:

```
https://<ip:port>/TestRESTServices/objects/test-folder
```

JSON data that I want to pass is:

```
{
   "name":"test-1",
   "parent-uuid":"126"
}
```

test-1 is the folder name which i want to create.
When i invoke this url with the data in Poster plugin in firefox via POST it works fine and folder test-1 is created.

```
 //using Content Type : "application/json"
```

How can I invoke/call this REST API using cURL ?
Need Help.

This is what i tried:

```
 curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"test-1","parent-uuid":"126"}' https://<ip:port>/TestRESTServices/objects/test-folder
```

It throws an error that `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have a REST API online to try it, but resources that I found suggest the following approaches:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "@issue.json" -u login:password http://redmine/issues.json
```

where the `issues.json` is a file containing the JSON request.

Resources I found useful:

[1](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request), [2](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_curl)

Hope it helps!

For Authentication : Give the userid/password as admin:password

```
  TOKEN=$(curl -s -k -X POST --basic -u "admin:password" "{host}/TestAuthServices/auth/tokens" | sed -rn 's/\{"Token":"([^"]+)".+/\1/p')
```

After getting this token call curl as:

```
 curl -s -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: X-SAML ${TOKEN}" -d '{"name":"test","parent-uuid":"126"}' "{host}/TestRESTServices/objects/test-folder"
```

Comment: SAML_AUTH_TOKEN is required for this for Authentification.Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I suppose your service requires authentication. I don't know how SAML works but I suppose first you have to make an authentication call, that returns a valid token that will be used afterwards in each call that you make as a header.

Comment: Yes. Solved. I am creating a TOKEN with the userid/password and using that token for the authorization purpose.

Comment: @VaibhavJain great. Thank you for the edit also, I suggest you edit your question as well to ask also about SAML authentication. Probably title can be edited also.

Comment: @Vibhav How are you generating SAML token with your credentials